# How to dynamically append a new line to a multiline textview

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I have a multiline  textview need to show the status of the server. So it should always add a new line when server status changes. However, When I use `mTextview.Text=string.Format("connected\n");` or `mTextview.SetText("...")` The new line doesn't show up immediatelly but show when all the processes are finished. Can anyone help me change it into a automatically show TextView? THX

```
logTextView.Text = string.Format ("Client log:\n");
.......
logTextView.Text=string.Format("Socket connected to 172.27.27.1\n");
.......
logTextView.Text = logTextView.Text+string.Format ("Start send image to server\n");
.......
```

Comment: You mention  "when all the processes are finished" it then shows up, is the processes and then the logTextView a synchronous process?

Comment: If you want to `add` text to a TextView then better use `textView.append("\nmy new text");`. But as you want to use this with sockets and your socket statements will be in a thread or AsyncTask you cannot use these 'change gui statements' there. Your app will crash.

Comment: @JamieRees I mean after the socket is closed. Everything is done then the text show up. This is definitely not what I want. I use `textview.append(" abc")` but still the same...

Answer (score 3):

you should use:

```
YourTextView.setText("Connected\n");
```

and to add multiple lines use:

```
YourTextView.append("another line\n");
```

Comment: did you accidentally set the maxlines for your multiline textview?

Comment: No, I set the `android:singleLine="false"`

Answer (score 0):

Create a new thread with that log process and immediately invoke it after some events occur.

For example:

```
class LogProcess implements Runnable {

    private String message;

    private TextView textView;

    public LogProcess(TextView textView, String message) {
        this.textView = textView;
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        textView.append(message);
    }

}
```

And then invoke it:

```
Thread logProcess = new Thread(new LogProcess(logTextView, message));
logProcess .start();
```